# Error in executing R dbReadTable and dbGetQuery against odbc connection to OBIEE

Tags: r, odbc, dbi, obiee

I'm using Microsoft R Open version 3.5 and the most recent packages
for odbc and dbi as of December 19, 2018 downloaded via CRAN.  I'm able to connect to the source, list tables, and confirm that the table exists per dbExistTable.   The driver is an oracle driver that connects to an OBIEE database.  I'm able to confirm that the driver, dsn, and query work independently from both Excel and SAS.

```
tbl_id <- DBI::Id(catalog="Human xxx", table="xxx")
dbExistsTable(con,tbl_id)
[1] TRUE
```

However I'm unable to read or query the tables, due to the error below.

```
dbReadTable(con,tbl_id)
```

> Error:  'SELECT * FROM "Human xxx"."xxx"'
>   nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1581: S1092: [NQODBC] [SQL_STATE: S1092]
>   [nQSError: 10071] The option type is out of range.

Also get the same error with a query:

> dbGetQuery(con,'SELECT Seg FROM "Account xxx"."Accounting xxx"')
>   Error:  'SELECT Seg FROM "Account xxx"."Accounting xxx"'
>     nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1581: S1092: [NQODBC] [SQL_STATE: S1092] [nQSError: 10071] The option type is out of range.

Where "Seg" is a simple text column of 10 characters.

Comment: What is your RDBMS? Oracle? `obiee` does not appear to be a direct database.

Comment: Please edit your post by tagging the database you are using (Oracle? SQL Server? DB2?). Also, please post the R odbc connection AND working Excel or SAS connection so we can compare your setup (redact any sensitive information).